# How to identify new item when iterating through the xsl for each?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have XML like below,

```
<employees>
 <employee>
  <id>1</id>
  <name>AAA</name>
 </employee>
 <employee>
  <id>1</id>
  <name>AAA</name>
 </employee>
 <employee>
  <id>2</id>
  <name>AAA</name>
 </employee>
 <employee>
  <id>2</id>
  <name>AAA</name>
 </employee>
</employees>
```

I'm iterating the above XML through xsl:foreach. I have a requirement that is after displaying the records of id '1' I have to keep one blank row. In XSL we can't store the id value of previous item to compare with the current element. So how can we Identify that item with new id?
How can achieve this by using ?

enter code here

Thanks,
Santhosh.

Comment: *"I'm iterating the above XML through xsl:foreach."*. Post relevant portion of your XSL and the output that you expect

Answer (score 0):

Q: I have a requirement that is after displaying the records of id '1' I have to keep one blank row.
You can use **preceding-sibling::** to check the "previous item".

```
   <xsl:variable name="this" select="." />
    <xsl:if test="$this/id != preceding-sibling::employee[1]/id" >
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
```

I would not use a for-each here (but allo possible) consider to use a template. Try something like this:

```
    <xsl:template match="employee">
        <xsl:variable name="this" select="." />
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:if test="$this/id != preceding-sibling::employee[1]/id" >
            <xsl:text>&#10; --------------;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
```